# Nice problem Which is bigger $e^a$ and $a^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> let $$a=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n+1}{3}\right)^n}{(n+1)!}$$

**My Question:**

> Which is bigger $e^a$ and $a^3$

I guess

> $$e^a=a^3$$

but I can't prove it,and I think this is nice problem.Thank you evryone

This problem from this http://www.math.org.cn/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3577&extra=&page=1

Comment: NO,I think is conveges,use Stirling's approximation

Comment: Where did you encounter this series?

Comment: why would the e-power and the exponential term be equal to each other?

Comment: It is highly likely these are equal... Numeric methods give identical approximations (I'm pretty sure those are approximations, not exact answers): [cubic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sum+n%3D0+to+infty+%28%28%28n%2B1%29%2F3%29^n%29%2F%28n%2B1%29!%29^3) and [exp](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e^%28sum%20n%3D0%20to%20infty%20%28%28%28n%2B1%29%2F3%29^n%29%2F%28n%2B1%29!%29&t=ff3tb01)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can "avoid" the Lambert $W$ function by skipping directly to its series representation.  We'll call upon the Lagrange inversion formula, which can be found in [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112106/5531).

Suppose we're looking for the smallest positive root of the equation $e^x = x^3$, which is also the smallest positive root of the equation

$$
\frac{x}{e^{x/3}} = 1.
$$

Let's call this root $a$.  The Lagrange inversion formula yields the desired series representation,

$$
\begin{align}
a &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left\{\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n-1} e^{nx/3} \right\}_{x=0} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left\{\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^{n-1} e^{nx/3} \right\}_{x=0} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)^{n}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

The solution to $e^a=a^3$ is given by the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

$a=-3 \text{W} \left( - \frac{1}{3} \right)$

Now, take a look at the [summation definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) of the Lambert W function.  If you change your limits so they start at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$, then it is easy to see that your summation is equal to the value of $a$ given above.

Comment: can you except use $Lambert W function$ methods? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Do you mean to say that you want a proof without using the Lambert W function?

Comment: Yes,That's my meaning.

Comment: The only other way is to find solutions to $\frac{a}{\text{ln }a} = 3$.  It is **very** difficult to do this without the Lambert W function.  I wouldn't even know where to start.

Answer (score -2):

well if e^a and a^3 are graphed
the results are a=1.857 and a=4.5364
lim a=>-inf e^a is 0 and lim a=>-inf a^3 is -inf
 lim a=>inf e^a/a^3
lim a=>inf e^a/3a^2
lim a=>inf e^a/6a
lim a>inf e^a/6 is inf by L'hopital rule
so e^a will be greater than a^3 from interval (-inf,1.857)u(4.53864,inf)

Comment: No,I don't think you

Comment: $e^a$ and $a^3$ are numbers.  It doesn't make since for $e^a$ to be greater than $a^3$ on an interval--what variable ranges over the interval?  $e$ is a constant, $a$ is a constant (if the series converges, but Wolfram says it does), and $3$ is a constant.  The answer is either $>$ or $<$.  There are no intervals in this problem.