# Roots of $x^x-\tan (x)$

Tags: analysis

I conjecture, that the function $f(x)=x^x-\tan x$ has exactly one root in any of
the intervals $\left[\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\pi,\dfrac{2n+3}{2}\pi\right]$ , where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. 
Does anyone know a proof?

I tried the trick using the function $g(x)=\log\left(\dfrac{x^x}{\tan x}\right)$ , which has the same roots, but it did not help either.

Comment: Is your function $x^x - tan(x)$ or $x^{x-tan(x)}$?

Comment: It is (x^x)-tan(x)

Comment: ok. oh, and by the way, just as a tip, if you want your math functions to have that math display, just surround your math with dollar signs. (i.e.: one dollar sign before and one dollar sign after)

Comment: I tried this for integrals, and it did not work. How could I display integral(x=0,1,exp(x)) in math display, for example ?

Comment: Sorry, there is no edit-button. Seems that only the user itself can edit the comment.

Comment: IMO this is a direct consequence of the intermediate value theorem and the fact that $x^x$ is monotone increasing for $x \ge 3\pi/2$, see Antonio Vargas' answer in the related topic at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110256/derivation-of-asymptotic-solution-of-tanx-x

Comment: oops sorry. Surround this with dollar signs: \int\limits_{x = 0}^{1}e^{x}dx

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: The indermediate value theorem only guarantees the existence of a root, it does not proof that there is exactly one.

Comment: @Peter: This comes from mononoty.

Comment: BTW: Are the intervals correct after edit? IMO: $\left[\frac{2n+1}{2\pi},\frac{2n+3}{2\pi}\right]$ should be replaced by $\left[\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi,\frac{2n+3}{2}\pi\right]$.

Comment: Yes, but to clarify, I did not edit it :)

Comment: If I search the roots of x^x-tan(x), what does the monotony of x^x help ? If tan(x) would decrease, so that x^x-tan(x) increases, that would be right. But tan(x) increases as does x^x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the equation is equivalent to
$$
\cot x=x^{-x}
$$

Comment: Short and simple ! :-)

Comment: A very good idea! The function $x^{-x}$ decreases very fast indeed, so my conjecture should be provable using this idea.

Comment: @Peter I guess so: the slopes of $x^{-x}$ and $\cot x$ near the intersection points are very far apart from each other.

Comment: Why has my comment been deleted ? Did it belong to a deleted answer ?

Comment: Just to repeat my comment : The fixpoint therem from banach can be used for the function g(x):=arctan($x^x$)+n$\pi$, where the nonnegative integer n depends on the wanted solution. It is not difficult to show, that the derivation of g is between 0 and 1 for x>=$e^{(-1)}$. For the interval [0,$e^{(-1)}$] , it is virtually trivial to show, that there is no solution for the equation tan(x)=$x^x$.