# Solving $\operatorname{ctg} x=x/b$

Tags: calculus, roots, perturbation-theory, trigonometric-series

I have no problems finding first solution (both: $b \to 0$ and $b \to \infty$). My solutions on photos.
I got stuck trying to find solution when $x \to \infty$. As I think, solution for $x$ will have $n$ in formula. I've no idea how to do this part.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I made all hard calculations using wolfram mathematica.

Comment: I've edited your post to use LaTeX markup for the formulas.  If you'd like, you can read about how to do this here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/117/5531 and here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/5531

Comment: You may also be interested in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/719244/5531 and this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/110256/5531

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing $x$ by $x+n\pi$ in the formula, so

$$
\frac{b}{x} = \tan x
$$

becomes

$$
\frac{b}{x+n\pi} = \tan(x+n\pi) = \tan x.
$$

Then it's still true in this new equation that $x \to 0$ as $b \to 0$ and $x \to \pi/2$ as $b \to \infty$, so you can use the same method you used to find the first solution.