# Can I solve this with a Lambert Function?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, transcendental-equations, lambert-w

New to W-Functions and do not understand it properly. How do I solve this equation? 
I know about numerical solutions (or graph solution), but I'm interested in pure algebraic solution if it exists.

$x^2 + 2^x = 100$

Comment: You can solve this equation using Newton-Raphson method too if you are allowed to do that.

Comment: If the equation could rewrite as $A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$, there will be solutions in terms of Lambert function. The equation you give does not fit. So, as Prasun Biswas commented, numerical methods ... except if you notice by inspection that there is a simple root (which is the case).

Comment: Yes, I noticed that x = 6. There is also a solution somewhere near -10. As for numerical methods, I'm interested in pure algebraic solution _if it exists_

Comment: I would add to your question that you know that numerical methods exist but that you are looking for an algebraic solution. Then people see that you share your thoughts about the problem. (questions sometimes get downvoted or closed if you don't show your thoughts about a problem)

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^2%2B2^x%3D100

Two solutions:$x=-9.99995$ and $x=6$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from:
$$x^2 + 2^x = 100$$
we can rewrite:
$$(x-10)(x+10)=-e^{x\ln 2}$$
$$x=-10-\frac{e^{x\ln 2}}{x-10}$$
Applying Lagrange inversion we obtain:
$$x=-10-\sum_{n=1}\left.D^{n-1}\frac{e^{xn\ln 2}}{n!(x-10)^n}\right|_{x=-10}$$
Fortunately the term $D^{n-1}\frac{e^{xn\ln 2}}{n!(x-10)^n}$ can be simplified by means of Bessel polynomials.
$$x=-10-\sum_{n=1}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!n!}\left.D^{n-1-k}e^{xn\ln 2}D^{k}(x-10)^{-n}\right|_{x=-10}$$
$$x=-10-\sum_{n=1}\frac{(n-1+k)!}{k!(n-1-k)!n!}\left.{(n\ln 2)}^{n-1-k}e^{xn\ln 2}(-1)^k(x-10)^{-n-k}\right|_{x=-10}$$
Remembering the Bessel polynomials:
$$B_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n+k)!}{(n-k)!k!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^k$$
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_polynomials
We can rewrite the Lagrange series:
$$x=-10-\sum_{n=1}{(n\ln 2)}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}e^{-10n\ln 2}(-20)^{-n}B_{n-1}\left(-\frac{2}{n\ln 2(-20)}\right)$$
$$x=-10-\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{nn!\ln 2 }\left((n\ln 2)e^{-10\ln 2}\over (-20)\right)^{n}B_{n-1}\left(-\frac{2}{n\ln 2(-20)}\right)$$

**References**
Other similar Math.stackexchange thread:
[Lagrange Bürmann Inversion Series Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849683/lagrange-b%C3%BCrmann-inversion-series-example/1179542#1179542)

I'm writing a paper on solution of transcendental equations of the form $$(x-a)(x-b)=\lambda e^x$$ and similar equations. A draft (some typo errors I have to fix and some partes to extend, but the work is essentially correct ) is here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00138v2 ("Generalization of Lambert W-function, Bessel polynomials and transcendental equations")

Comment: I have edited in order to fix some errors in formulas.