# Roots of $\tan x - x$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, roots

The function $\tan x - x$ has exactly one root $x_n$ in the interval $(n\pi, (n + \frac{1}{2})\pi)$. Show that
$$x_n = n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{n\pi} + r_n$$
where $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n r_n = 0$.

I think I should try to use Taylor expansion some way, but I am not seeing how to do this.

Comment: It helps to make a plot in order to see where the intersections occur, and what points would be best for Taylor expansion.

Comment: This question is a special case of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/110256/5531).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but let $y_n=\tan[x_n-n\pi]$. Then we have
$$\tan x_n - n\pi = x_n - n\pi.$$
Thus, using $\tan(x_n)=\tan(x_n-n\pi)$,
$$y_n - n\pi = \arctan(y_n).$$
Now use $\arctan(y)+\arctan(1/y)=\pi/2$ to obtain
$$y_n+\arctan(1/y_n)=n\pi + \pi/2.$$
Now, because $y_n \rightarrow \infty$, you can use a Taylor expansion of $\arctan$ around 0. This should give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_n = \pi/2-x_n + n\pi$, then $y_n\in(0,\pi/2)$ and
$$\frac{1}{\tan y_n}=\frac{\pi}{2}-y_n+n\pi\Leftrightarrow \tan y_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-y_n+n\pi}$$
Since $y\in(0,\pi/2)$, it follows that
$$\frac{1}{n\pi}> \tan y_n > \frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi}\\
\Rightarrow 1 > n\pi\tan y_n  > \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{2n})}$$
By squeeze theorem we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\pi \tan y_n=1$, but we also know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\tan y_n}{y_n} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan y_n}{y_n} = 1$ therefore
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n\pi \,y_n = 1\\
\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n\pi(\pi/2 - x_n + n\pi) = 1\\
\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n\pi(x_n - \pi/2 + n\pi - \frac{1}{n\pi})=0
\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n\pi r_n=0$$

Comment: Your forgot to remove a $\pi$ in the formula right before the words "By squeeze theorem".

Comment: @user thank you, i fixed that