# The roots of $\tan(x)-x$ approaches $\frac{\pi}2 + n\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, improper-integrals

I wrote a proof on [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/User:Sandbox/Du_Bois-Reymond_Constants/Example/First) of this problem:

> Prove $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \left|\dfrac d {d t} \left(\dfrac {\sin t} t\right)^n\right|\mathrm d t$ diverges for $n=1$.

To fill the gaps in the proof, I need to prove the following two inequalities (Also see the [talk page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/User_talk:Sandbox/Du_Bois-Reymond_Constants/Example/First))

$$\tag1
t_n< \frac {\pi} 2 + n \pi$$
and
$$\tag2
|\sin(t_n)|\ge|\sin(t_1)|$$
where
$(t_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is all the positive roots of $t=\tan(t)$ in increasing order.

I am convinced that inequalities $(1),(2)$ holds, by looking at the intersections $(t_n,t_n)$ of the graphs $y = x$ and $y = \tan x$.

$t_n$ is closer and closer to the lines $x=\frac{\pi}2 + n\pi$ which are asymptotes to the graph of $y=\tan x$.

---

To prove $(1)$, I use the monotonicity of the function $\tan(x)-x$ on each interval $\left(n\pi,\frac{\pi}2+n\pi\right)$

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\tan(x)-x]=\sec^2(x)-1\ge0$$

so the function $\tan(x)-x$ is continuous and increasing on each interval $\left(n\pi,\frac{\pi}2+n\pi\right)$

and $\tan(x)-x<0$ at $x=n\pi$

and$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}2+n\pi}\tan(x)-x=+\infty$$
so $\tan(x)-x$ has a unique root on each interval $\left(n\pi,\frac{\pi}2+n\pi\right)$.

---

To prove $(2)$, we only need prove that $|\sin(t_n)|$ is increasing.
$$\tan(t_n+\pi)-(t_n+\pi)=\tan(t_n)-t_n-\pi=-\pi<0$$

so $\tan(t_n+\pi)-(t_n+\pi)<\tan(t_{n+1})-(t_{n+1})$

but both $t_n+\pi$ and $t_{n+1}$ belong to $\left((n+1)\pi,\frac{\pi}2+(n+1)\pi\right)$ and the function $\tan(x)-x$ is increasing on this interval

so $t_n+\pi<t_{n+1}$

so $|\sin(t_n)|<|\sin(t_{n+1})|$

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

---

I have a follow-up question:

From the above proof of $(2)$, we have that $(\frac{\pi}2 + n\pi)-t_n$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below by $0$, so it converges. Can we show that the limit is $0$? That is,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\pi}2 + n\pi)-t_n=0$$

Comment: Which step are you unsure of? Be specific please. We are not a proof-checking site.

Comment: @Mike I'm unsure of the proof of $(2)$.

Comment: Oh, I find this question is a special case of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/110256/5531).

Comment: Probably you had in mind the inequality $\pi(n-1/2)<t_n<\pi(n+1/2)$.  On the interval you've given the function $\tan x-x$ is NOT continuous.

Comment: @user Thanks! I have fixed it. I should have $t_0=0$ and $\pi<t_1<\frac{3\pi}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct and easily understandable.

What concerns your question the property can be also easily demonstrated.

Assume
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi-t_n=\epsilon>0.\tag1
$$
Since $\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi-t_n$ is decreasing sequence this means:
$$
\forall n: \left(n+\frac12\right)\pi-t_n>\epsilon\implies t_n<\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi-\epsilon\implies\tan t_n<\cot\epsilon.\tag2
$$
Here we took into account that $\tan x$ is increasing continuous function for $\pi n<x<\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$.

In view of $t_n=\tan t_n$ the last inequality implies:
$$\forall n: t_n<\cot\epsilon<\infty,\tag3$$
which is however impossible since $t_n$ is unbounded (particularly $t_n>n\pi$). This contradiction demonstrates that the assumption $\epsilon>0$ was false.