# $\tan(x) = x$. Find the values of $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

How can I find the possible values of $x$ for:

> $\tan(x)=x$

mathematically?

Comment: $x=0{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: You can get very nice estimates for the roots. Some non-trivial mathematics is involved.  There is as far as I know no "closed form" expression for the family of solutions.

Comment: Note that for $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$, only $x=0$ is a solution. But there are infinitely many solutions with $x$ outside this region, and, as Andre says, it is unlikely they have a closed form.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Is infinte many solutions possible? When I tried to do this graphically , I got only three solutions.

Comment: Let $k$ be any integer. Then there is exactly one solution $x$ in the interval $(k\pi -\pi/2,k\pi+\pi/2)$

Comment: When you did it graphically, you may not have set your calculator window to be large enough.

Comment: I was talking about degrees not radian.

Comment: Degrees, radians, it doesn't matter much. The analysis for $\tan x=ax$ is quite similar to the one for $a=1$.

Comment: I guess there are no rational solutions except 0.

Comment: In degrees, there are three solutions between the two vertical asymptotes closest to the origin.  In radians, there is only the one trivial solution between those two asymptotes and all others are farther from the origin.

Comment: There is a Bessel J zero function solution and a [series solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98107/rearrange-y-x-tan-y-to-solve-for-y-given-x/4626750#4626750) with Stirling numbers. If you want the this solution posted, then please say so as there are already 3 answers here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation of asymptotic solution of $\tan(x) = x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110256/derivation-of-asymptotic-solution-of-tanx-x)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I gave a talk on this equation in April 2006 and (a .pdf version of) the [LaTeX slides I used](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/13-2052391-7014308-591164/tan(x)%20=%20x.pdf) may be of interest to you.

See also the math StackExchange question [Derivation of asymptotic solution of $\tan (x)=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110256/derivation-of-asymptotic-solution-of-tanx-x). Finally, see the posts in this January 2006 sci.math thread: [Regarding tan(x) = x](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/1KOaZXdFAG4/m/TcyHql37MA4J).

Answer (score 17):

There is no closed form for the solutions of $ \tan(x) = x $, but let me state a few interesting facts. Let $ (\lambda_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ be the sequence that lists the positive solutions of $ \tan(x) = x $ in increasing order. Then

- $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda_{n}} = \infty $.
- $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda_{n}^{2}} = \frac{1}{10} $.

Comment: Guess Im not the only one who knows this :p +1 from me.

Comment: @mick: Oh, you mean the second identity?

Comment: Yes ... What else ?

Comment: @HaskellCurry: Can u provide me some links to the explanations of this properties. Right now I am having difficulty understanding how these properties came.

Comment: You can refer to this other MSE thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75206/sum-of-the-squares-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-fixed-points-of-the-tangent-functio.

Comment: It is inmoral to give out such results without a source!

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=x$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}...$$
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}...$$
Your question is equivalent to solving the equation

$$x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots=x-\frac{x^3}{2!}+\frac{x^5}{4!}-\cdots$$
$$x^3\left(\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{2!}\right)-x^5\left(\frac{1}{5!}-\frac{1}{4!}\right)+x^7\left(\frac{1}{7!}-\frac{1}{6!}\right)+\cdots=0$$
Evidently giving
$$x=0$$

The other solutions are given by the equation
$$\left(\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{2!}\right)-x^2\left(\frac{1}{5!}-\frac{1}{4!}\right)+x^4\left(\frac{1}{7!}-\frac{1}{6!}\right)-\cdots=0$$

But I don't know if there is a way to get from that to a closed form.