# Solution to $\frac{x}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{x}\right)}=\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In the following equation, is it possible to solve for numerical value of $x$.

$$\frac{x}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{x}\right)}=\pi$$

Comment: No problem, take your time.  We just need to understand the question properly before trying to answer it.

Comment: Now, what do you want? An analytical or a numerical solution? For the former, there is no closed form. However, if you want a numerical solution, you can try to solve it with Newton's method.

Comment: I would like a numerical solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right)=\operatorname{cotan}(\alpha)=\dfrac{1}{\tan(\alpha)}$, the given equation is equivalent to:

$$\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{x}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{x}$$

Setting $a=\dfrac{\pi}{x}$, we have to look for non-zero solutions $a_k \ (k \in \mathbb{Z^*})$ of equation  $\tan(a)=a$. There are an infinity of them: see graphics below. 
As a consequence, the solutions of the initial problem are $x_k=\dfrac{\pi}{a_k}.$

Let us fix $k$; a very efficient way to obtain $a_k$ is to invert relationship

$$\tag{1}\tan(a)=a.$$

One might be tempted to invert (1) by writing plainly into $a=\tan^{-1}(a)$.

In fact, due to the periodicity of tangent function, inversion of (1) is

$$\tag{2}a=f_k(a) \ \ \  \text{where} \ \ \ f_k(a):=\tan^{-1}(a)+k \pi$$

(as can be understood by the graphical representation of $f_k$, which is the $k$th branch in blue on the graphics, resulting from a $k$ times "upper translation" from mother function $\tan^{-1}$).

Solving (2) is easy by using the classical "fixed point" sequence built in this way:

$$\alpha_{p+1}=f_k(\alpha_{p}) \ \ \ p=0,1,2...$$

(with any initial $\alpha_0$). It converges very rapidly to the solution $a=a_k$ of (2) due to a small value of the derivative of $f_k$ in the vicinity of this root $a_k$.

Remarks:

1) Two very interesting references : [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269939) (contains very interesting pointers) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110256), the latter with a solution using Lagrange inversion formula.

2) I have used notation $\tan^{-1}$ because it is now very widespread (maybe due to hand calculators ?), although notation $\operatorname{atan}$ or $\operatorname{arctan}$ is less misleading . More precisely, $y=\tan(x)$ has $f_k(x)$ as its reciprocal function for its $k$th "branch". Sometimes one meets the concept of a unique  **multivalued** inverse function ; the natural context in which this concept has its full meaning is complex function theory.

[image]

Comment: very interesting !

Comment: Whoa, those are trippy graphs you got going.  Good idea for whenever I need wavy looking stuff.

Comment: @Simple Art With the risk of being seasick when glaring too much at them.

Comment: MathJax hint: we have `\operatorname{atan}` to do not-so-common functions.

Comment: @Simple Art You are right. I modify it my text.

Answer (score 8):

As JeanMarie wrote in his answer, we face the problem of solving of $a$ equation $$\tan(a)=a$$ As said, this kind of equation does not show analytical solutions and numerical methods are required. If you have to do it, to mkae life easier, I would suggest to look for the zero's of $$f(a)=\sin(a)-a\cos(a)$$ which is much better conditioned since the vertical asymptotes are removed. Using Newton for the $k^{th}$ root, starting from a guess $a_0=\frac{(2k+1)\pi }2$, the method will update it according to $$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)}$$ In the present case, this would give $$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{1}{a_n}+\cot (a_n)$$

Let us see how this would work for $k=10$; the table below reproduces the iterates of Newton method 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 32.986722862692829004 \\
 1 & 32.956407635437229892 \\
 2 & 32.956389039832967134 \\
 3 & 32.956389039822476725 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is quite fast for a very high accuracy of the solution.

We can also approximate the solution using Padé approximants built around $a_0$; to avoid even quadratic equations, we could write $$f(a)=\sin(a)-a\cos(a)\approx \frac {P_1(a)} {Q_m(a)}$$ Where $P_1(a)$ is a first degree polynomial and $Q_m(a)$ is a  polynomial of degree $m$. For sure, the solution will be the root of $P_1(a)=0$.

I give you below the result of the simplest approximations  $(m=1,2)$
$$a_{(1)}=\frac{  2 \alpha ^3-3\alpha}{2 \alpha ^2-1}$$
$$a_{(2)}=\frac{6 \alpha ^4-13 \alpha ^2+3}{6 \alpha ^3-7 \alpha }
 $$  $$a_{(3)}=\frac{24 \alpha ^5-68 \alpha ^3+37 \alpha }{24 \alpha ^4-44 \alpha ^2+9}$$ $$a_{(4)}=\frac{120 \alpha ^6-420 \alpha ^4+361 \alpha ^2-45}{120 \alpha ^5-300 \alpha
   ^3+141 \alpha }$$ $$a_{(5)}=\frac{720 \alpha ^7-3000 \alpha ^5+3542 \alpha ^3-1031 \alpha }{720 \alpha ^6-2280
   \alpha ^4+1742 \alpha ^2-185}$$ using $\alpha=\frac{(2k+1)\pi }2$.

I give below  a table of the results for the first twenty solutions.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{exact} & a_{(1)}  & a_{(2)}\\
 1 & 4.49341 & 4.49529 & 4.49346 \\
 2 & 7.72525 & 7.72562 & 7.72526 \\
 3 & 10.9041 & 10.9043 & 10.9041 \\
 4 & 14.0662 & 14.0663 & 14.0662 \\
 5 & 17.2208 & 17.2208 & 17.2208 \\
 6 & 20.3713 & 20.3713 & 20.3713 \\
 7 & 23.5195 & 23.5195 & 23.5195 \\
 8 & 26.6661 & 26.6661 & 26.6661 \\
 9 & 29.8116 & 29.8116 & 29.8116 \\
 10 & 32.9564 & 32.9564 & 32.9564 \\
 11 & 36.1006 & 36.1006 & 36.1006 \\
 12 & 39.2444 & 39.2444 & 39.2444 \\
 13 & 42.3879 & 42.3879 & 42.3879 \\
 14 & 45.5311 & 45.5311 & 45.5311 \\
 15 & 48.6741 & 48.6741 & 48.6741 \\
 16 & 51.8170 & 51.8170 & 51.8170 \\
 17 & 54.9597 & 54.9597 & 54.9597 \\
 18 & 58.1023 & 58.1023 & 58.1023 \\
 19 & 61.2447 & 61.2447 & 61.2447 \\
 20 & 64.3871 & 64.3871 & 64.3871
\end{array}
\right)$$ As you can see, without almost any calculations, we quickly have six exact significant figures.

**Edit**

Considering the case where $\alpha \to \infty$ and expanding the result obtained from Pade approximants, we have $$a_{(1)}=\alpha -\frac{1}{\alpha }-\frac{1}{2 \alpha ^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^5
   }\right)$$ $$a_{(2)}=\alpha -\frac{1}{\alpha }-\frac{2}{3 \alpha ^3}-\frac{7}{9 \alpha
   ^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^7 }\right)$$ $$a_{(3)}=\alpha -\frac{1}{\alpha }-\frac{2}{3 \alpha ^3}-\frac{61}{72 \alpha
   ^5}-\frac{563}{432 \alpha ^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^9 }\right)$$ $$a_{(4)}=\alpha -\frac{1}{\alpha }-\frac{2}{3 \alpha ^3}-\frac{13}{15 \alpha
   ^5}-\frac{83}{60 \alpha ^7}-\frac{61}{25 \alpha ^9}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^{11}
   }\right) $$ $$a_{(5)}=\alpha -\frac{1}{\alpha }-\frac{2}{3 \alpha ^3}-\frac{13}{15 \alpha
   ^5}-\frac{2999}{2160 \alpha ^7}-\frac{160129}{64800 \alpha
   ^9}-\frac{1215311}{259200 \alpha ^{11}}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^{13}
   }\right)$$So, thinking about the asymptotics, I tried $$a=\alpha+\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {A_i}{\alpha^{2i+1}}$$ and a (tedious) expansion work leads to $$a=\alpha -\frac{1}{\alpha }-\frac{2}{3 \alpha ^3}-\frac{13}{15 \alpha ^5}-\frac{146}{105 \alpha ^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^9
   }\right)$$ Applied to $k=10$, this leads to $a=32.956389039822530434$ to be compared to the result of Newton method. Applied to $k=1$, six significant figures are already obtained.

Comment: Very interesting ! Thank you Claude !

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thanks ! Among my passions : Taylor series, Pade approximants, high order Newton methods, asymptotes removal !!

Comment: the passage to find the zeros of $f(a)$ is clever: thanks for showing it

Comment: @GCab. I spent most of my (long) life removing vertical asymptotes in order to have a better conditioning of equations.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici In fact, in my solution (In which I have modified in particular the graphical part), I have also removed the asymptotes by taking multivalued function arctan. But I agree that your solution is simpler.

Comment: @JeanMarie. I noticed this way and I found interesting for approaching this problem as you did. Your answer is much better now. Nice illustration.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici 1) I have found an interesting reference in Math SE using Lagrange inversion formula 2) Besides, I remember now that I have seen that equation $\tan(\lambda_k)=\lambda_k$ gives the eigenvalues of a certain functional operator, but I don't remind where. Would you know references?

Comment: Another interesting thread (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/269939) that I have added to my answer ; thanks to it, I have found back the connection to the operator I was looking for.

Comment: Many years (probably > 30) ago, while browsing through a British math journal (might have been the Journal of the London Mathematics Society), I came across an article by G. H. Hardy on the solutions to $\tan(x) = x$. He gave a fairly complete asymptotic description of the roots near $k\pi$. For some reason, this has stuck in my head.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot solve this, but with some simple rewriting, we have

$$x=\pi\tan\left(90-\frac{180}x\right)$$

Since $\tan(\theta)$ for any $\theta\in\mathbb Q$, and where we use degrees, we have

$$\tan(\theta)\in\mathbb A$$

That is, it will be an algebraic number.

Now, that means that since $\pi$ is transcendental, $\pi\tan\left(90-\frac{180}x\right)$ must be transcendental.

Thus, $x$ cannot be any rational number.  It is also not a multiple of $\pi$, since we are in radians.  So the answer is not trivial.

It is also not possible to solve, due to the fact that if $\theta$ is not rational, $\tan(\theta)$ has no closed form, working in radians.  For example, noone knows what $\tan(\sqrt2)$ is exactly, so if $x$ is not a rational number... then we cannot solve the equation in closed form.

Looking at a graph, we have an infinite amount of interception points:

[image]

Indeed, the behavior of the $\tan$ around $x=0$ is not very good for most numerical methods.

Comment: Why $x$ should be a rational number?

Comment: @AlexSilva I just proved it can't be rational.  And since $\tan(\theta)$ has no closed form whenever $\theta\notin\mathbb Q$, when working in degrees, it is not possible to solve.

Comment: This is not the good way to solve this equation. My answer shows that, by transforming in into equation $tan(a)=a$, there is no numerical problem.

Comment: @JeanMarie :(  But it is also not possible to solve $\tan(x)=x$ in closed form (not that I solved it either)

Comment: I completely agree. But the OP didn't speak of closed form solutions. He wants information about numerical solutions. Moreover, it is even possible  in this case to provide a method for obtaining very good approximations.

Comment: @JeanMarie Mmmhhmmmm... I will merely say the question has been through many stages since I last checked.

Comment: That's right : I would say that convergence to a rational question has necessitated some iterations steps.

Comment: @JeanMarie To much oscillation between iterations too.  Not very stable XD

Comment: @Simple Art :):):):):)

Comment: why $360/x$ , should be $180/x$

Comment: @GCab Sorry, that was my bad.

Comment: good, but ..there is another

Comment: @GCab if the edit seems really trivial, feel free to edit yourself.  And thanks for the many catches of my mistakes.  $\ddot\smile$

Comment: yes, direct editing would be quicker, however I deem it is more "polite" to advise the author.

Comment: @gcab so do I, especially if you yourself mess something up.

Answer (score 0):

I started trying out different values for $x$ and seeing how much effect they have on the problem

So after fiddling with that for a wile I found that as the value of $x$ gets closer and closer to infinity. the equation actually gets closer and closer to being true (that is closer to equaling $\pi$). so if $x$ is equal to infinity then the equation must be true (or equal to $\pi$). So $x$ in this equation must be infinity. But that also explains why the equation is impossible to solve because you cant work out the tangent for. $$\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{\infty}\right)$$