# Solve $x = \frac{1}{2}\tan(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

I did this using trial and error, but I was just wandering if there is an algebraic way of solving this?

I thought about double angle formula but that doesn't work properly does it?

I then tried writing it in the form $x \cdot 2 \cot(x) = 1$ but even then, I can't solve it properly by re-writing $\cot(x)$ because of the $x$ outside the brackets.

Anybody know how I would do this algebraically?

Comment: To begin with, a plot will show you that there is exactly one solution in each of the intervals $(-\pi/2 +k\pi,\pi/2+k\pi$.

Comment: I seem to recall this question here already...

Comment: I've seen such an equation occur in the context of quantum mechanics, where the eigenvalues of some hamiltonian are given by the set of solutions to such an equation. I strongly suspect there is no "nice" way to find these solutions, however, insofar as there is no combination of elementary functions that'll give you the solutions (save $x = 0$). Instead, it's more interesting to develop asymptotics for these solutions. The idea is to approximate $\tan$ by vertical lines at $\frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi$ as $k$ ranges over the integers.

Comment: I work with such a functions pretty often, so I confirm - there's no "nice" solution for it. They can be found numerically though, and that's what we do.

Comment: @Kaish: Here is a [*plot*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bx%2C+Tan%5Bx%5D%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-2+Pi%2C+2+Pi%7D%5D) and here are [*numerical solutions*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bx+%3D%3D+%281%2F2%29Tan%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D) to go along with the other comments. Regards

Comment: As GEdgar remarks, this has come up before. See [Derivation of asymptotic solution of $\tan (x)=x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110256/derivation-of-asymptotic-solution-of-tanx-x?lq=1) and [Solution of $\tan x = x$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/solution-of-tanx-x) and [The Remarkable Equation $\tan x = x$](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/13-2052391-7014308-591164/tan(x)%20=%20x.pdf) (the last one is for the notes I used in an April 2006 talk I gave on the solutions).

Comment: Explicit series solution for inverse of $\frac{\tan(x)}x$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98107/rearrange-y-x-tan-y-to-solve-for-y-given-x/4626750#4626750). Your equation is $\frac{\tan(x)}x=2$

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It cannot be solved algebraically as it is a transcendental equation.

Comment: There are trascendental equations that can be solved algebraically. For instance, $\sin x = \cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the roots are transcendantal numbers, which cannot be expressed in terms of a finite number of elementary functions. But they can be expressed on the forme of series :

[image]