# Solve $x - 2\arctan(x)= 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$x - 2\arctan(x)= 0$.

I can find one root (0) from the equation

$\tan(x/2) = x$

but there are two others, namely

($-2.3312, 2.3312$)

that I don't know how to find. Looking for help! Thanks :)

[link to WolframAlpha solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-2arctan%28x%29=0)

Comment: if WolframAlpha couldn't find an analytical (exact) solution, there probably isn't one.  Who's asking?  How are you expected to find them?  By the way, try "\tan" and "\arctan" for $\tan$ and $\arctan$

Comment: First year calculus course. This is a part of a functional analysis excercise, where $f(x) = x-2\arctan(x)$. I don't really know how I am expected to find them, using math i guess (tee-hee).

Comment: Did you attempt to find $f'(x)$, the derivative?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the problem is fairly easy. My classmates have been finding the answer with plotting calculators or via wolframAlpha (or such). Thought there was an analytical way to solve the roots of the equation vs numerical. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: @AntonPopov : if this is part of a "functional analysis exercise", then why are the tags (algebra-precalculus) and (trigonometry)?  What exercise exactly is this part of?

Comment: You can rearrange into $\frac{\tan(y)}y=2$ and use [this series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98107/rearrange-y-x-tan-y-to-solve-for-y-given-x/4626750#4626750)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you must use a numerical approximation method.
In a calculus book usually you find the *bisection method* after introducing the intermediate value theorem and the *Newton-Raphson method* in the chapter on derivatives (near you find also the *secant method*).
Choose one and you are done (with the comfort of a calculator).

A plot is useful to orient: for example, in this case the roots can be found as abscissas of the points of intersection of the curve $y=\arctan x$ and the line $y=x/2$.

Comment: Thanks! That was a great answer :)