# Solve $\cos(x)(\pi/2-x)\gt \frac{3.544}{N}$.

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a way to solve this equation (find $x$)?

$\cos(x)(\pi/2-x) \gt \frac{3.544}{N}$

where $-\pi/2 \lt x \lt \pi/2$, and $N$ is positive number $\gt$ 2.

Comment: Do you have any progress on solving this?

Comment: yes, I tried this matlab code
syms N x;
solve(cos(x)*(pi/2-x)-3.544/N,x)
it give me can't solve, when I put value for N, it gave me  the solution.

Comment: Please edit your question on what you have tried, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "Solve?" What would the solution look like?

Comment: If you let $y=\pi/2-x$ and $\alpha =3.544/N,$ this is equivalent to $y\sin y>\alpha$ for $y\in(0,\pi).$

Comment: find the max of your function, than max<3,5.../N  there are all n>2 true. The best would have been for you to plot the function!

Comment: The maximum of $y\sin y$ is where $y>0$ and $$\sin y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$$ It seems unlikely there is a closed formula for this equation - the best you'll do is numeric approximation.

Comment: The maximum of $x\sin(x)$ is where $\frac{d\sin(x)x}{dx}=\sin(x)+x\cos(x)=0\iff \tan(x)+x=0$. There is likely a closed form with Mathematica’s BesselJZero function and a [series solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98107/rearrange-y-x-tan-y-to-solve-for-y-given-x/4626750#4626750)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thomas Andrews commented, let $y=\frac \pi 2 -x$ and $\alpha=\frac {3.544}N$ to reduce the problem to
$$y\,\sin(y)=\alpha$$

For *approximations*, use my favored $1400^+$ years old approximation of the sine function

$$\sin(y) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -y) y}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -y) y}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0\leq y\leq\pi$$

To give you an idea of the accuracy, the norm
$$\int_0^\pi \Big(y\,\sin(y)-  \frac{16 (\pi -y) y^2}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -y) y}  \Big)^2\,dy$$ is explicit and its numerical value is $1.0585\times 10^{-5}$ (which is quite good).

So, the problem is to solve for $y$ the cubic equation
$$16 \,y^3-4 (4\pi-\alpha)\, y^2-4 \pi  \alpha\,  y+5 \pi ^2  \alpha =0$$

Its discriminant is always positive as long as $\alpha \leq  1.817696$ (this is the case even for $N=2$). So, three real solutions.

Using
$$p=\frac{\alpha ^2+4 \pi  \alpha +16 \pi ^2}{48} \qquad \text{and} \qquad q=\frac{\alpha ^3+6 \pi  \alpha ^2+246 \pi ^2   \alpha -64 \pi ^3}{864}$$ the three solutions are
$$y_k=\frac{4 \pi -\alpha}{12}+2 \sqrt{\frac{p}{3}}\,\cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \pi  k-\cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{3
   \sqrt{3} q}{2 p^{3/2}}\right)\right)\right)$$ for $k=0,1,2$.

Since $y_2 <0$

- the smallest root of the equation is $y_1$
- the largest root of the equation is $y_0$

Just a few checks (the solutions being computed using Newton method)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 N & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 3 & 1.29691 &  1.29648 & 2.65187 &  2.65154   \\
 4 & 1.06898 &  1.06813 & 2.80231 &  2.80085   \\
 5 & 0.93334 &  0.93243 & 2.88018 &  2.87842   \\
 6 & 0.83970 &  0.83885 & 2.92854 &  2.92674   \\
 7 & 0.76980 &  0.76907 & 2.96165 &  2.95989   \\
 8 & 0.71497 &  0.71436 & 2.98579 &  2.98411   \\
  9 & 0.67045 &  0.66995 & 3.00419 &  3.00260   \\
 10 & 0.63332 &  0.63294 & 3.01868 &  3.01718 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For large values of $N$, using Taylor series and power series reversion, we could simply use
$$y_1=\sqrt \alpha \left(1+\frac{\alpha }{12}+\frac{29 \alpha ^2}{1440}+\frac{263
   \alpha ^3}{40320}+O\left(\alpha ^4\right) \right)$$

$$y_0=\pi-\frac{\alpha} \pi\left(1+\frac{\alpha }{\pi ^2}+\frac{\left(12+\pi ^2\right) \alpha
   ^2}{6 \pi ^4}+\frac{\left(15+2 \pi ^2\right) \alpha ^3}{3
   \pi ^6}+O\left(\alpha ^4\right) \right)$$ which, for $N=10$ would give $0.63291$ and $3.01720$ which are much better than the roots of the cubic equation.

Answer (score -1):

let  $y=\pi/2−x$
this is equivalent to

$y\sin(y)\gt3.544/N$

for $y\in (0,\pi)$

firstly, lets do a numerical solution and plot N vs y.

we can use this matlab code

```
    % Define the range of N values
N_values = 3:100; 

% Initialize arrays to store y values for each N
y_values = zeros(length(N_values), 1);

% Solve for y for each N and x
for i = 1:length(N_values)
    N = N_values(i);
    
    % Solve the equation for y using fsolve
    initial_guess = pi/2; % Initial guess for y
    options = optimoptions('fsolve', 'Display', 'off');
    y_values(i) = fsolve(@(y) y .* sin(y) - 3.544 ./ N, initial_guess, options);
end

% Plot N vs y
figure;
plot(N_values, y_values*180/pi);
xlabel('N');
ylabel('y');
title('Plot of y as a Function of N');
grid on;
```

After plotting and see the curve, we can approximate the solution to this equation $\frac{a}{N^b}$.

This is a matlab code to find value of a,b according solution curve:

```
initial_params = [1 0.1];
fun = @(params, N) params(1) ./ (N .^ params(2));
params = lsqcurvefit(fun, initial_params, N_values, y_values');
```

So, the solution will be:

$y>\frac{2.1497}{N^{0.5344}}$

$\pi/2-x>\frac{2.1497}{N^{0.5344}}$

$x<\pi/2-\frac{2.1497}{N^{0.5344}}$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).